# python arg values from php

Tags: php, python

m stuck at a web interface for a python script, the thing is that I need to read inputs from user, and run those as argument values on a python script, but it is not working heres my code

index.php

```
 <html>
 <body>

 <form action="programa.php" method="post">
   Name: <input type="text" name="longitud"><br>
   E-mail: <input type="text" name="angulo"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="correr">
 </form>
```

programa.php

```
<?php $longitud=$_POST["longitud"];

    $angulo=$_POST["angulo"]; ?>
    <h1>Corriendo programa con  <?php echo $_POST["longitud"]; ?> mm de longitud<br>
     y  <?php echo $_POST["angulo"]; ?> grados de angulo</h1>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <?php 
    $a=exec('sudo python /var/www/python/programa.py $longitud $angulo');
    echo $a;
    ?>
```

I visited the error log and printed me this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/python/programa.py", line 7, in <module>
script,long_barra,angulo = argv
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
[Mon Nov 10 22:36:53 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] PHP Notice:  Undefined 
index:   longitud in /var/www/Maquina/programa.php on line 22
[Mon Nov 10 22:36:53 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: 
angulo in /var/www/Maquina/programa.php on line 24
[Mon Nov 10 22:36:53 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: 
longitud in /var/www/Maquina/programa.php on line 25
[Mon Nov 10 22:36:53 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.3] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: 
angulo in /var/www/Maquina/programa.php on line 26
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/python/programa.py", line 7, in <module>
script,long_barra,angulo = argv
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/python/programa.py", line 7, in <module>
script,long_barra,angulo = argv
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

The script on programa.php reads the post values, but doesnt pass the argv to python script, how can I solve this

tx in advance

Comment: Just a suggestion in regards to security, don't use sudo when executing commands based on user input from a web interface and if you do filter with escapeshellarg().

Answer (score 0):

The reason your arguments aren't being passed to python is the single quotes in your `exec()` call. This sends python the literal strings "$longitud" and "$angulo", not the values of said variables. Instead, use double quotes and PHP will substitute the variables with their values.

So, change your `exec()` call to:

```
$a=exec("sudo python /var/www/python/programa.py {$longitud} {$angulo}");
//      ^                 notice the double quotes                    ^
```

The curly braces are not necessary in this case, but I recommend them for readability.

Or, you can access the values directly from `$_POST` without assigning the values to variables like so:

```
$a=exec("sudo python /var/www/python/programa.py {$_POST['longitud']} {$_POST['angulo']}");
```